# How to run a Robot Framework test with 2 different users in 2 different browser windows simultaneously?

Tags: firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver, plone, robotframework

In some of our Plone add-ons I have a Robot Framework test to verify the functionality provided by [plone.app.lockingbehavior](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.app.lockingbehavior)

The test opens 2 browser windows (one using **localhost** and the other using **127.0.0.1**) and logs 2 different users on the Plone site to verify if an instance of a content type is blocked when one user is editing it.

This was working, for example, on [collective.cover](https://github.com/collective/collective.cover/blob/master/src/collective/cover/tests/test_locked_cover.robot) until some months ago when a change in some of the versions of the stack were updated ([circa 20 Aug](https://github.com/collective/collective.cover/commit/a8f6172ebd20e422cbd2e53c4533e99752504397)).

I noticed that when I switch back to the first browser window the user is switched also to the one on the second browser window; this should not be happening in normal operation, but seems that the cookies in tests are being shared by mistake.

Here are some screenshots:

Browser window 1: User **Owner** editing some piece of content on **localhost**:

[image: User Owner editing some piece of content]

Switch to browser window 2: User **Site Administrator** trying to edit the same piece of content on **127.0.0.1**:

[image: User Site Administrator trying to edit the same piece of content]

Switch to browser window 1: User **Owner** became user **Site Administrator** on **localhost**:

[image: User Owner became user Site Administrator]

How can I run a Robot Framework test with 2 different users in 2 different browser windows simultaneously?

Comment: If it was working but then stopped, you should investigate your dependencies and report there (maybe start at p.a.robotframework)

Answer (score 1):

As long as the browsers are different - i.e. not two instances of Firefox - this should be possible to do in a single test on a single box.

You can make the users different by adding the credentials to the site URL (this works for Chrome and FF but gets blocked by IE)

Code is in C# but should be doable in python for Robot Framework

```
// Create IWebdriver instance for user 1
IWebDriver user1InFF = new FirefoxDriver();
user1inFF.Navigate().GoToURL("http://user1:user1Password@localhost");

// Create IWebDriver instance for user 2
IWebDriver user2InChrome = new ChromeDriver();
user2inChrome.Navigate().GoToURL("http://user2:user2Password@127.0.0.1");

// Use both instances in the test

user1InFF.DoSomething();

user2InChrome.CheckSomething();

etc...
```